# How can I pass arguments off a QFile to other function on QT?

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring, qfile

I have this code, and i want to pass the directory off the file selected on the "void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() " function to the " char* videoName ". How can I do it?
 I dont know how to do it, please help me!!!!1

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
char arg1;
int stop;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{



ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   char* videoName = ???
   Mat FrameAtual, suave_image;
   vector<Vec3f> circles;

   namedWindow("Video Processado", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   VideoCapture capture(videoName);
   if (!capture.isOpened())
       printf ("1");

           bool stop(false);

                                                                             //Condi��o de parada se usu�rio pressionar alguma tecla durante execu��o

   double FrameRate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);                                   //Obter taxa de quadros do v�deo a ser processado
   int Delay = 1000 / FrameRate;
   //cout << "Delay = " << Delay;

   while (!stop) {
       if (!capture.read(FrameAtual))                                                   //L� pr�ximo frame, se existir; se n�o existe sai da execu��o
           break;

       cvtColor(FrameAtual, FrameAtual, CV_BGR2GRAY);

       GaussianBlur(FrameAtual, suave_image, Size(5, 5), 1.0);
       HoughCircles(suave_image, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 230, 120,    100, 25, 80);
       vector<Vec3f>::const_iterator itc = circles.begin();
       while (itc != circles.end()) {
           circle(FrameAtual, Point((*itc)[0], (*itc)[1]), (*itc)[2],  Scalar(255), 2);
           ++itc;
       }

       imshow("Video Processado", FrameAtual);

       if (cv::waitKey(Delay) >= 0)                                                 //Introduz delay antes de passar ao prox frame ou interrompe se usu�rio pressionar tecla
           stop = true;
   }






}









void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(

            this,
            tr("Open File"),
            "/home/pi",
            "All Files (*.*);;"

            );
QMessageBox::information(this,tr("File Name"),filename);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways:

you are using the variable in same "mainwindow" class it self.

And also based on function name, I assume you are trying to use the "videoname" in another slot.

**so just declare "videoname" as a class private variable.**

and assign the filename/dirctory name to your "`char*`" using "`qStr.toLatin1().data()`"

**Pseudo code below:**

```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {

    //if you want file name
 QString filename  = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(

                this,
                tr("Open File"),
                "/home/pi",
                "All Files (*.*);;"

                );

    _videoname = filename.toLatin1().data(); //_videoname (const char*) is your class private variable. you can use any where with in the class.


    //Similary if you want directory name 

    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                    "/home/pi",
                                                    QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                    | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);


    _dirname = dir.toLatin1().data();//_dirname (const char*) is your class private variable. you can use any where in the class.


    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("File Name"),filename);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it compiles , but doesnt work. I just want to sent the way of the file  i selected to the namevideo variable. For example "home/pi/video.avi". Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean with full file path?

Comment: The above code gives full path. Do you want trim it and send only ""home/pi/video.avi"?

Comment: if that is the case, call "filename   = filename.mid(filename.indexOf("home/pi"),filename.length()+1);" before assigning to _videoname

Comment: You are right, i want full path, but i dont know why it doesnt work.

Comment: i noticed another problem with "capture" function. this "videpcapture" open CVV function takes string as input. try "std::string str(_videoname)" and pass "capture(str)"

Comment: I think the variable  videoname is still not receiving the filename .

Comment: Thanks , i just exclude the variable videoname and used "std::string str(_filename.toLatin1().data();)" and pass "capture(str) ". And now it worked!!!!